# Recursive program C to Prolog

Tags: for-loop, recursion, prolog

I'm trying to implement a recursive program in prolog. I have an idea on how I would implement it in a procedural language like C, but can't figure out how to do it in prolog.

How I'd do it in C:

```
int function_1(int m){

  int i, a;

  if(check_solution(m))
    return 1;

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){

    a=function_2(i);

    if (function_1(a))
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

function_2 and check_solution are both non-recursive functions.

I'm having a hard time getting into prolog's way of solving problems, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your function return when the loop reaches the end? How does `function_2` look? What about `check_solution`? A working implementation in C would help.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I realised just now I had the return value of function_1 missing, I've added it. Regarding function_2 and check_solution, they are both non-recursive.

Comment: I would suggest to start with something simpler. Like 1) how to convert a function into a Prolog predicate. 2) How to write a *simple* recursion in Prolog (no loops), 3) How to simulate a loop. then you can combine these together

Answer (score 0):

Many times the best way to solve a problem in Prolog is to rethink it in Prolog. Some problems, however, by nature lend themselves best to an imperative approach, which is what languages like C are good at. Without knowing much more about the actual problem the function is solving, we're unfortunately left with transliterating the C function to Prolog. A problem solved imperatively in Prolog doesn't really give you strong insight to Prolog's way of solving problems (declaratively). But here's one rendition in Prolog of the presented C function:

```
predicate_1(M) :-
    (   check_solution(M)
    ->  true
    ;   between(1, 10, X),
            predicate_2(X, A),
            (   predicate_1(A)
            ->  !
            ;   fail
            )
    ).
```

In this case, `predicate_1/1` will *fail* (corresponding to `return 0`) or *succeed* (corresponding to `return 1`). I am assuming that `check_solution/1` is written to *succeed* versus "return truthy", and *fail* versus "return falsey". Finally, I expect `predicate_2/2` to always succeed and instantiate `A` with something.